# three.js - link camera rotation to mobile device movement inside div

Tags: javascript, three.js

Is there a way to have the camera rotation in [this demo](https://jsfiddle.net/1dy343xy/) be controlled by mobile device movement as well as mouse movement as it currently is? This has been implemented for mobile [here](http://richtr.github.io/three.js/examples/misc_controls_deviceorientation.html) but not alongside with mouse. This is what currently controls camera rotation for mouse:

```
    function render() {
        var timer = -0.0002 * Date.now();
        camera.position.x += ( mouseX - camera.position.x ) * .05;
        camera.position.y += ( - mouseY - camera.position.y ) * .05;
        camera.lookAt( scene.position );
        pointLight.position.x = 1500 * Math.cos( timer );
        pointLight.position.z = 1500 * Math.sin( timer );
        renderer.render( scene, camera );
    }
```

The goal is to put it in a div on a page that can be scrolled - I've seen this implemented in a single full-viewport page, but not as an element in a longer page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first check if it is a mobile device or not.
if it is: use DeviceOrientation ...
else: use the code wrote for mouse.

to check if is it mobile:

```
functionisMobile() {

    if (navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i)
        || navigator.userAgent.match(/webOS/i)
        || navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i)
        || navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i)
        || navigator.userAgent.match(/iPod/i)
        || navigator.userAgent.match(/BlackBerry/i)
        || navigator.userAgent.match(/Windows Phone/i)
    ) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}
```